# 'Anastrophe' a hyponym of 'hyperbaton'?

Tags: rhetoric

> [[Source 1:]](http://wordsmith.org/board/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=168732#Post168732) 'an anastrophe is always a type of hyperbaton, but a hyperbaton is not necessarily an anastrophe'.
>
> [[Source 2:]](http://humanities.byu.edu/rhetoric/Figures/A/anastrophe.htm) Anastrophe is most often a synonym for hyperbaton, but is occasionally referred to as a more specific instance of hyperbaton: the changing of the position of only a single word.

Please explain Source 1? What if 'hyperbaton' reorders `only a single word` but at different places? Are there any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) I would recommend to use only the OED in the first instance. Avoid trouble. If you happen to be using a mac it's built right in...

[image]

[image]

(2) **Regarding extremely obscure words like "anastrophe"**.  Don't forget that the only "meaning" of words in English is "how people use them".

(There is NOT, for example, a committee of people who decide an "official" meaning.)

With words that are used very little, **there is no real meaning**.  The only place you could find these words used commonly, is - for example - in very narrow scientific literature dealing with certain fields of perhaps linguistics or computer speech recognition.

In those extremely rare cases: it could be that (let's say) Professor X, happens to always use "anastrophe" in some certain way.  Or it could be that (say) at Apple, in the Siri research department, they have a particular way of always using "hyperbaton".

To repeat, very uncommon words simply **do not have** a firm meaning in any real sense.

If, for some reason, you needed to express **precisely** the concept "single word moved, at different places" - say you were writing a research paper - you would have to simply state "I am going to use anastrophe in exactly this way _ _ _ _" and then do that.

You can easily google up some books that use "anastrophe", for example

[annoying long link here](http://books.google.fr/books?id=D6jU7q1Xkf0C&pg=PA215&lpg=PA215&dq=anastrophe%20linguistics%20research&source=bl&ots=Z-qYurfYBT&sig=UkHqdqNaFSAISFFS10bybar2dqo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DrBMVLHHJsz1aMGGgvgJ&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=anastrophe%20linguistics%20research&f=false)

[image]

The people who write dictionaries just do this, and then make something up to meet deadline.

**Important note...**

Be very careful about using "wiki" type things as references.

So, if you're looking for "examples" you can google up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anastrophe .  What you see there is:

some person has copied flotsam and jetsam from around the internet and pasted it in there. It means **almost nothing** and could well be **totally incorrect**. The concept behind wikipedia is: "on the internet you can find almost any nonsense. here on wikipedia people copy and paste all the nonsense together in one place".  By all means a few wiki articles are terrific because, by coincidence, some expert may have most recently edited the answer. But you have to be extremely careful.

Comment: That's not the OED, by the way. That's the ODE, a completely different dictionary.